# How do I start Super Melee mode in The Ur-Quan Masters?

Tags: star-control-2

I've figured out how to configure team names, membership, and control.  But beyond that screen, I can't seem to find how to initiate battle.

After clicking the "BATTLE!" button, I'm presented with a screen that has a black background and two blue boxes.  Each box has a team name, and icons representing the ships in each team and their values.  Each box also has two buttons - a question mark and a red X.

At this point, my normal controls (Up/Down/Left/Right/Control/Shift/Escape) seem to not function.  Is there something wrong with the game, or my system?  Or, does the control set change specially for Super Melee mode at this point?  How should I proceed?

This is on a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 system, with UQM version 0.7.0.

Comment: That sounds like the ship selection screen, where both players select the ships they want to use in the upcoming battle. Probably the solution is indeed to find the right controls ... but I don't remember what they are.

Answer (score 3):

Before clicking the battle button, on the setup screen you'll see which team is controlled by which player.

[image: battle setup screen]

By default, the first team is controlled by the AI while the second team is controlled by the player. This is where things can get a bit confusing, if the bottom player is set to human control then the controls for "player 1" will be used, while if the top player is set to human the controls for "player 2" will be used. The exact keys which can be used by player 1 or player 2 can be set in the UQM setup menu.

By default, player one should be able to select a ship using the arrow keys and the enter key to select something, while player two is able to use ESDF and the Q button to select a ship.

Comment: This drove me nuts on a few occasions too. I find the player 2 controls almost unusable, so you'll usually want to set the human player to player 1 (the bottom of the screen).